# Certain Vim digraphs do not display properly

Tags: vim

Superscript 2,3,+ subscript 4 do not display properly. Superscript 2 displays as `<8e>` and superscript 3 displays as `<8f>`, and subscript 4 displays as `ㄙ`, superscript + displays as `ס`.

In my `.vimrc` the following is set:

```
execute "digraphs 0S " . 0x2070
execute "digraphs 1S " . 0xB9
execute "digraphs 2S " . 0xB2
execute "digraphs 3S " . 0xB3
execute "digraphs 4S " . 0x2074
execute "digraphs 5S " . 0x2075
execute "digraphs 6S " . 0x2076
execute "digraphs 7S " . 0x2077
execute "digraphs 8S " . 0x2078
execute "digraphs 9S " . 0x2079

execute "digraphs +S " . 0x207A
execute "digraphs -S " . 0x207B
execute "digraphs =S " . 0x207C
execute "digraphs (S " . 0x207D
execute "digraphs )S " . 0x207E
execute "digraphs nS " . 0x207F
 
execute "digraphs 0s " . 0x2080
execute "digraphs 1s " . 0x2081
execute "digraphs 2s " . 0x2082
execute "digraphs 3s " . 0x2083
execute "digraphs 4s " . 0x2084
execute "digraphs 5s " . 0x2085
execute "digraphs 6s " . 0x2086
execute "digraphs 7s " . 0x2087
execute "digraphs 8s " . 0x2088
execute "digraphs 9s " . 0x2089
```

There are some other anomalies but I would imagine any solution that addresses those 4 can be applied to the rest. I've tried setting encoding to utf-8 and using decimal values instead of hex but the problem persists. I feel like it's the font but I've tried about a dozen different fonts and each results in the same weird characters. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello! I think this question would be better suited for [Vim Stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). If you agree, consider [flagging it for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, exactly, are you redefining all those digraphs to their built-in values? And How, exactly did you determine that subscript 4 was `ㄙ`?

`₄` is obtained with `<C-k>4s` while `ㄙ` is obtained with `<C-k>s4` so it looks to me like you are simply pressing the keys out of order.

Comment: Yep, I was just doing it out of order, out of order seems to work for sub/superscript 4-9 but has problems with 1-3 and o ther chars. Thanks!